# Spring 3 MVC Hibernate 3.5.4 hibernateTemplate not closing connections (non-transactional)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

We are using Spring MVC 3.0.5.RELEASE with Hibernate 3.5.4-Final without transactions. Every time we access the database through the hibernateTemplate it creates a new connection and seemingly never closes them.

UPDATE: we've set maxActive and maxIdle to 5. The application will hang when it tries to open the 6th connection. We allow 100 mysql connections.

Our hibernateTemplate is Autowired, so we're not directly managing these connections. Any ideas on how to make sure these connections are closed?

Here's our spring configuration for hibernate:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxActive">
        <value>5</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxIdle">
        <value>5</value>
    </property>
    <property name="removeAbandoned">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout">
        <value>30</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<alias name="dataSource" alias="userInfoDataSource"/>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>                
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Here is our HibernateRepository implementation:

```
package com.dataAccess.impl;

import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public abstract class HibernateRepositoryImpl<T> implements com.dataAccess.Repository<T> {

  @Autowired
  protected HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

  public List<T> find(String query) {
    return hibernateTemplate.find(query);
  }

  @Override
  public void saveOrUpdate(T ENTITY) {
    hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(ENTITY);
  }

  @Override
  public List<T> find(DetachedCriteria criteria) {
    return hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
  }

  @Override
  public void delete(T ENTITY) {
    hibernateTemplate.delete(ENTITY);
  }
}
```

Here is an example of our we are using it, which seems to leak connections:

```
package com.dataAccess.impl;

import com.domain.Trigger;
import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class TriggerRepository extends HibernateRepositoryImpl<Trigger> {
  public List<Trigger> getActiveTriggers(Integer patientId) {
    DetachedCriteria findActiveTriggers = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Trigger.class).add(
        Restrictions.and(
            Restrictions.eq("patientId", patientId),
            Restrictions.eq("active", true)
        )
    );
    return super.find(findActiveTriggers);
  }
  public List<Trigger> getInActiveTriggers(Integer patientId) {
    DetachedCriteria findActiveTriggers = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Trigger.class).add(
        Restrictions.and(
            Restrictions.eq("patientId", patientId),
            Restrictions.eq("active", false)
        )
    );
    return super.find(findActiveTriggers);
  }

  public Trigger get(Integer triggerId) {
    return hibernateTemplate.get(Trigger.class, triggerId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem ended up being some legacy code which called was chaining several methods together, where the method in the middle of creating the connection -- so the connection was never getting assigned (tough to spot) nor was it ever getting closed. This code was indirectly getting loaded and I wrongly suspected my Hibernate/Spring configuration to be at fault.

If you hit similar issues be wary of lines of code that read:

```
connectionManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(..).<whatever>
```

The getConnection() call likely opens a new connection and it nor the prepared statement every have a change to get closed.

Comment: Good catch! Glad I only lost 30 minutes to The Google after talking to you about it. :)

Comment: Also, I wonder if you just changed the connectionManager reference to a Spring-provided DataSource whether that would have fixed it.

Comment: We updated it to use the spring provided data source (the problem still existed until we split apart the chained call so we could explicitly close the Connection). I very much appreciate your help the other day!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you aren't using a transactionManager then you should be closing the Hibernate session after each of the operations in your `HibernateRepositoryImpl` class.

What you have would probably be considered a bug in most situations - you are opening new Hibernate sessions, but they are never being closed - the only reason why you are seeing the SQL statements actually executed against the database is because you have the `hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion` property set to true.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I have no idea how to close connections, since everything is managed and autowired up through spring and HibernateTemplate doesn't provide any mechanism that I can tell. I have moved the project to use transactions but that doesn't solve the issue either. I am now trying to utilize my app container (Tomcat 6) to manage the connections and provide a way to access them via JNDI, but Spring is unable to locate the dataSource bean.

Comment: *I have moved the project to use transactions but that doesn't solve the issue either* have you looked at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html ? Often-times you can simply annotate (service) methods with `@Transactional`; make sure you wire up a `TransactionManager`

Comment: Yeah, when I moved things to use transactions I marked all Repository classes as @Transactional and wired up the Hibernate TransactionManager. I had even tried moving to C3P0's connection pooling, but still no go. I am currently stripping away everything and adding pieces on by one to see if I can pinpoint when things go awry.

Comment: Do you see the Hibernate Sessions being closed, if you turn up the logging on org.hibernate and org.springframework?

Comment: Thanks for your responses matt. After a bunch of digging the culprit was in some legacy code which was chaining a call which created a connection (so it never got assigned nor released). That legacy code ended was indirectly getting loaded in several cases (which led me to believe it was the hibernate/spring side that was the culprit).

Answer (score 0):

Also please make sure that you are not creating more than one instance of `HibernateTemplate`, 
i

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");
Object o=context.getBean("hibernateTemplate");
```

The object `o` has to be cached somewhere and returned when your app code is asking for instance of `hibernatetemplate`.

Thanks