# Does flush and clear methods on hibernate template locks the database table

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

In my application I am using Spring 4.0 declarative transaction management and hibernate in dao layer...I use hibernate template for insert and updates. ..since I have to insert a large number of records I do call flush and clear methods on hibernate template..after every 50 records..But what I have observe is it locks that particular table while processing. ..only after all records are inserted in db I can fire a query on db...
Is this behavior correct ??? Does it have any proper solution

Comment: Did you change the default flush mode?
 Try like this : 
 Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
 session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);

Comment: I did not change default values and secondly I do not use session factory ..I use hibernate template directly and call flush and clear on that

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following data source properties to your datasource configuration.

```
<property name="maxActive" value="100"></property> 
<property name="maxIdle" value="30"></property> 
<property name="maxWait" value="10000"></property>
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978613/spring-3-mvc-hibernate-3-5-4-hibernatetemplate-not-closing-connections-non-tran) also.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I use hibernate 4.. i dont think above properties will help..My question here is ..Is this hibernate feature to take the lock on database in above situation

Comment: Did you try adding that or just assuming? Here is one more reference, how you can add these properties. http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/33265-hibernate-template-not-closing-connections

Comment: I use websphere as application server and configure datasource at server level where connections are well managed. Do you want me to changes ds configurations at server level?

Comment: I think it's worth trying. I don't know about websphere but in tomcat, we could add these properties in server.xml.